# Passing php results into an html script as arguments

Tags: javascript

I have an html script that includes several data numbers.. i want to replace these numbers by other numbers form my database using php code.. i have the html form and the php code but i don't know how to pass the php results as parameters to my form..

here is a part of my script:

```
<script>
                        var barChartData = {
                        labels : ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","jul"],
                        datasets : [
                            {
                                fillColor : "#FC8213",
                                data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
                            },
                            {
                                fillColor : "#337AB7",
                                data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
                            }
                        ]

                    };
                        new Chart(document.getElementById("bar").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);

                    </script>
```

i want to replace the numbers in `data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]` by numbers I get from my database by a php code... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use json_encode function:

```
<script>
                    var barChartData = {
                    labels : ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","jul"],
                    datasets : [
                        {
                            fillColor : "#FC8213",
                            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
                        },
                        {
                            fillColor : "#337AB7",
                            data : <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
                        }
                    ]

                };
                    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);

                </script>
```